# Aggregate in MongoDB Atlas trigger not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I have this aggregation pipeline i wrote in NodeJS in my Atlas Trigger :

```
  const pipeline = [
    {$match: {"score": {$gt: 0}, "update": true}},
    {$setWindowFields: {sortBy: {"score": -1}, output: {"rank": {$denseRank: {}}}}},
    {$merge: {into: "ranking"}}
  ];
  
  await ranking_col.aggregate(pipeline);
```

I have written this pipeline in python first for testing and it's working just fine :

```
self.db.ranking.aggregate([
            {
                "$match": {
                    "score": {"$gt": 0},
                    "update": True
                }
            },
            {
                '$setWindowFields': {
                    'sortBy': {'score': -1},
                    'output': {
                        'rank': {
                            '$denseRank': {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$merge": {
                    "into": "ranking"
                }
            }
        ])
```

I have no errors from the Trigger logs but it seems that the pipeline is simply not executed as it should modify the ranking as it's done in python.

Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong here ?

EDIT : The database scheme (as simple as the query is)

See below one document of `ranking_col` :

```
{
  "_id": "7dqe1kcA7R1YGjdwHsAkV83",
  "score": 294,
  "update": false,
  "rank": 0,
}
```

The aggregation is simply here to calculate the `rank` attribute according to the `score`.

Comment: If you could share additional information, what kind a trigger is it, what configurations it has. did your "python" run on the same database?. schema example. all this could help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes the python runs against the same database. The trigger is a scheduled trigger. 
The database scheme is very simple i will edit the question.

Comment: A few more questions, do you have any other triggers running? if so how many? what is the scale of this collection? what atlas tier is your db on?

Comment: For now i am not in production, so i have only this trigger running for testing purposes, the collection has 50 documents for now but at scale can have millions. 
My Atlas tier is a M10 replica set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so the issue relies in the Mongo driver the function uses on atlas and your understanding of it.

`aggregate` returns an `AggregateCursor`, which means until you trigger it no command is actually getting executed, this means your trigger is actually running fine, but because no one is using the cursor it just exits the function without doing anyways.

A super simple solution would be to just add `.toArray()`, this will convert the cursor to an array of documents. essentially triggering the functionality:

```
await ranking_col.aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's working fine now ! Can you please have a look at my other MongoDB related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73428588/nin-not-working-mongodb-atlas-trigger-node-js 
I will grant you the bounty in 5h i can't for now unfortunately

Comment: Looks like it the same problem, your second `find` does not have `toArray` and it's it's return value is `Cursor`. :). you could use `findOne` instead as you're already adding a limit 1, just note that the sort options are passed in a different way for it..

Comment: Thank you again i feel stupid i didn't check again my question but indeed it's working fine with the `toArray()` :). Oh right, but you advise me to use `findOne` instead of this ? For performance reasons ?

Comment: There's hardly any actual difference (if you don't need the cursor properties), i just find it more elegant as it cleans up the code.

Comment: Alright perfect then, no i don't need the cursor so i will opt for it thanks.