# $nin not working mongodb Atlas trigger Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have the following code in my Atlas trigger function :

```
  const existings = await test_collection.find().toArray();
  var ids = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < existings.length; i++) {
    ids.push(existings[i]._id);
  }

  console.log("Existing ids : ", ids);
  const value = await user_collection.find({"_id": {$nin: ids}}).sort({quantity: -1}).limit(1);
  console.log("Value is : ", JSON.stringify(value));
```

The logs are showing this :

```
Logs:
[
  "Existing ids :  vfLGh8QVOsbmz1,F7Mqe1YwH5fsV83",
  "Value is :  {}",
]
```

The python equivalent that is actually working :

```
 def test(self):
        test = self.db.test.find()
        ids = []
        for t in test:
            ids.append(t["_id"])
        print(f"Existing ids : {ids}")
        value = self.db.users.find({"_id": {"$nin": ids}}).sort("quantity", pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1)
        print(f"Value is : {value[0]}")
```

And python logs :

```
Existing ids : ['vfLGh8QVOsbmz1', 'F7Mqe1YwH5fsV83']
Value is : Value is : {'_id': '6GzgNoZFR2H7hfdzI3', 'username': 'test3'}
```

I have tried without the `sort` operator to be sure the issue would come from `$nin`, i have the same empty output without the `sort`

Comment: Is there another process inserting documents?  Why do you expect more `"_id"`s after retrieving all docs and then searching for extra `"_id"`s?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, please have a look at the collections they are different. I fetch all documents (2) from a collection test, then i want to take a user from the `users` collection which was not already in test collection.

Comment: Ah, I see now - my oversight.  Yeah, the difference is curious.  Out of curiosity, if you replace `$nin` with `$in`, do you get the expected results?

Comment: Well it's a good question ! i have tried and the result is also empty... which makes me think there is really something wrong with my syntax perhaps... It can't a bug in both operators.

Comment: I'm a javascript noob so I don't think I'll be of much help.  I guess you'll need to do some debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `toArray()` method after the limit(1) to convert the value and to not get a cursor.

This look like :

```
const value = await user_collection.find({"_id": {$nin: ids}}).sort({quantity: -1}).limit(1).toArray();
```

and your `value` const should  have the result.